# Where is found the original library of the PBFT consensus algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, consensus, byzantine

In the [PBFT paper written by Miguel Castro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/thesis-mcastro.pdf) it has been mentioned:

(In Abstract:)

> "BFT has been implemented as a generic program library with a simple
> interface."

(Also in page 71:)

> "The algorithm has been implemented as a generic program library with
> a simple interface. Thelibrary can be used to provide
> Byzantine-fault-tolerant versions of different services ... The library is implemented in C++."

Where is this library found?
if it is an open source code.

While there are several implementations of the PBFT consensus in github repositories , I could not find the original library in github.

I'd intend to use the PBFT original code in a distributed network.

**P.S.** If this site is not the related one to post this question, please let me know the relevant site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this link on the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20031002114315/http://www.pmg.lcs.mit.edu/bft/) is the earliest available snapshot of the webpage that contains links to the [requested source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20031002114315/http://pmg.lcs.mit.edu/%7Erodrigo/bft-base-src-rh72.tar.gz).